# importing component for enzyme throws an error unexpected token on shallow (it's on Typescipt)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babeljs

When importing a component to test with enzyme im getting the following even after adding the presets on babel

```
const App = shallow(<App />);
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <


//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@babel/preset-react"
  ], 
  "plugins" : ["transform-export-extensions"]
} 



//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest",
    },
    testRegex: "(/tests/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    collectCoverage: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv:  [
        "<rootDir>/tests/setEnzyme.js"
    ] // enzyme config
};


// app.test.js
const { React } = require('react');
const { shallow } = require('enzyme');

const { App } = require('../src/app');

describe('App component', () => {
    it('shoule render', () => {
        const App = shallow(<App />);
        const div = App.find("div");
    })
})


// app.tsx

import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>Test</div>
    )
}

export {
    App
}
```

Comment: You did not create the project with create react app?

Comment: no. i prefer making it from the ground up (for now)